# Is it possible to increment a scalar reference in Perl?

Tags: perl, pass-by-reference

Say I have a number, `$x = 0;` and I want to increment it with a subroutine, but the subroutine won't be returning its value:

```
sub increment {
    my ($var) = @_;

    my @list = (
        'a',
        'b',
        'c',

        ...

        'x',
        'y',
        'z'
    );

    return $list[$var++];
}

while ($x < 10) {
    print increment($x);
}
```

As-is, this will print `aaaaaaaaaa` forever instead of `abcdefghij`.  If I replace `increment($x)` with `increment(\$x)`, it converts the scalar address to a decimal number and increments that instead.  In the above scenario, it ends up throwing an error because 25423331 or whatever isn't a valid array element.

If $x were an element in a hash or an array, I could pass the parent as a reference to have the original modified:

```
$x = {'val' => 0};
while ($x->{'val'} < 10) {
    print increment($x);
}

sub increment {
    ...
    return $list[$var->{$val}++];
}
```

How can I modify the original value of a scalar reference?

Comment: Will point out - you don't actually need to do all that. You can instead `my $letter = 'a'; print $letter++ for ( 1..10 );`

Comment: Even though I provided an answer that does what you're asking, I would generally recommend that you avoid doing stuff like this. It's a little disorienting to have the loop index incremented "at a distance".

Comment: @Sobrique I can't believe that works, but the behavior is even [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement). Thanks for teaching me something new today.

Comment: @MattJacob The [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) works the same way, allowing you to do things like `say for 'a' .. 'zz';`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I knew about that one, but I didn't think that incrementing a string would even work, let alone produce a somewhat desirable output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a reference to the variable to modify.

```
sub increment {
    my ($ref) = @_;
    ++$$ref;
}

my $i = 0;
say $i;  # prints 0
increment(\$i);
say $i;  # prints 1
```

You could also take advantage of the fact that Perl [passes by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference).

```
sub increment {
    ++$_[0];
}

my $i = 0;
say $i;  # prints 0
increment($i);
say $i;  # prints 1
```

---

But hiding the increment as such is a really bad idea. Either iterate over a list,

```
for my $x ('a'..'z') {
   ...
}
```

Or write an iterator.

```
sub make_iter {
   my @list = @_;
   return sub {
      return @list ? shift(@list) : ();
   };
}

my $iter = make_iter('a'..'z');
while (my ($x) = $iter->()) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: @DaveSherohman: In any language that has pass-by-reference, if you assign a pass-by-reference parameter to another regular local variable, that variable is an independent copy of the original.

Comment: Yep, I stand corrected. I happen to be at YAPC::EU at the moment, so I found a Perl 5 core dev and asked about the difference between the aliasing of @_ and pass-by-reference.  His answer was "oh, it is a pass-by-reference". Since I was wrong and this comment discussion isn't likely to be helpful to anyone in the future, I'm deleting my earlier comments.

Answer (score 2):

You need to dereference `$var` inside the subroutine, like this:

```
my $x = 0;

say $x;  # prints 0
foo(\$x);
say $x;  # prints 1

sub foo {
    my $y = shift;
    $$y++;
}
```